# while replacing the input string spaces with underscore and then checking it it does not replaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

```
    game=input("enter student name to update report card: ")
    nn=game.replace("  ", "_")
    mycursor.execute("show tables")
    klm = mycursor.fetchall()
    if (nn,) in klm:
        b=int(input("enter sno: "))
        mycursor.execute("select * from {} where sno='{}'".format(nn,b))
        xer=mycursor.fetchall()
            
    else:
        print("no student record found")
```

this does not execute the if statement it directly goes to the else even though i have table name some_one, it shows no record found

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nn=game.replace("  ", "_")`  has 2 spaces in your code

Try with

`nn=game.replace(" ", "_")` has one space

```
game=input("enter student name to update report card: ")
nn=game.replace(" ", "_")
print(nn)
#output
enter student name to update report card: some one
some_one
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the tuple `(nn,)` in your table names. Just try searching for the string itself like this:

```
if nn in klm:
```

Comment: yes i used it but no luck

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: i used mysql database

Comment: Try using this SQL query instead: `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables`